# Escape regex in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex

Essentially what i am doing is finding a piece of text in a textfile. The text is user specified so before i stick it into my regex expression i need to escape it all so `.` are `\.` and that something like `{0, 3}` is the string literal instead of part of the regex expression. Is there a function i can use to escape it? if not what chatacters should i stick `\` in front of to ensure a valid regex statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Regex.Escape` method -

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,.,
>   `#`, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This
>   instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters
>   literally rather than as metacharacters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx

Comment: oh wow its even called escape and in the very class i am using. This is a sign i should stop programming for the moment +1 and accept when i get back